# Linking an object file that contains stdio functions with ld, no crt0.o found

Tags: linker, ld, crt

Recently I've been learning linker and trying to link simple files using ld, but then, I failed to do so (probably because of architecture x64?... I cannot really tell). Here are the files I used:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun(int x);

int main(){
    int i = fun(10);
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
int fun(int x){
    return x+10;
}
```

I compiled them with gcc -c commands and then linked them into a single file with command:

```
ld -r -o a.o main.o fun.o
```

and, finally, I wanted to make the a.o file into an executable. I have read /usr/lib/ctr0.o is needed, but not having found it, I tried /x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o (and learned it did not work). What is a replacement for crt0.o then? I do not have crt0.o in my system (I did my search, but probably not where I should have). What other file can I use in its place, so that the command:

```
ld a.o <SOME_FILE> -lc
```

is going to produce executable output?

Answer (score 0):

> trying to link simple files using ld

You should *never ever* use `ld` directly on UNIX, unless you are linking some special program, like the kernel or the boot loader.

For "regular" user-level programs, *always* use the appropriate compiler frontend (`gcc` for "C", `g++` for "C++").

P.S.

If you want to know where `crt0.o` comes from, try `gcc -v a.o`, and `gcc` will *show* you.

Comment: I know I should never use ld in 'normal' projects, but the case is I am learning how does it work. And yes, I did tried verbose but there is no crt0.o there

Comment: "there is no crt0.o"-- yes, *there is*. It's just called `crt1.o`, or maybe `Scrt1.o`. The *point* is that the exact name and location depends on a lot of things, which the compiler driver knows about, and you don't. "learning how ..." -- this is good, but your should have mentioned that in your question.